# Can running virtual machine's CPU/memory 's SUM is greater than the physical host?

Tags: virtual-machine

I have a physical server as the host, its hardware:  10 core CPU 10G RAM,

Can I run 20 virtual server which has 1 core CPU 1G RAM at the same time? (assuming these virtual server is consuming very low CPU/RAM.e.g. using 5% CPU , and 0.1G RAM)

If I can, which kind of software should I use?  vsphere?

Comment: If the performance requirements aren't too high you can overcommit RAM and CPU. The hypervisor choice depends on many factors and can't be answered simply. We use KVM within our openstack cloud.

Comment: Generally speaking, No.  The virtual machine resources (all them them combined) fit within the host machine.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it.

This concept is "overcommit", and the open-stack's answer is:

- CPU allocation ratio: 16:1   ( virtual machine : physical machine)
- RAM allocation ratio: 1.5:1  ( virtual machine : physical machine)

and also, some of my friends told me that:

1. Don't overcommit if your physical machine is strong enough for the VM.
2. Don't overcommit too much. always left some resource out there for your physical machine.
3. openstack + KVM and vSphere are both very good(some friend said this is vSphere is not stable, some friend said vSphere is very stable , has been running for 3 years .. )

see: https://docs.openstack.org/arch-design/design-compute/design-compute-overcommit.html